# Sobre o DATEADD, comparação com mês anterior, quando existe um filtro de Mês único

Tags: powerbi

Tenho a seguinte situação conforme imagem abaixo.

Quero fazer uma análise individual do mês, logo, todos os meses que não o selecionado estão com filtro 'desligados' e isso faz com que minha medida com valor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`Valor Orçado D-1 = CALCULATE([Valor Orçado];DATEADD(BaseCalendario[Início do Mês];-1;MONTH))` sempre tenha valor vazio.

O local marcado com Valor Executado D-1 era para mostrar o custo executado de Direito de Passagem do Mês anterior. da mesma forma que a seguinte imagem (feita em exel) faz:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguma forma de manter meu relatório com filtro de mês único e mostrar o valor do mês anterior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já tentou usar a função **PREVIOUSMONTH()** ?

```
Valor_Orçado_M-1 = 
                   CALCULATE(
                             [Valor Orçado]; 
                             PREVIOUSMONTH(BaseCalendario[Data])
                             )
```

Você também está usando uma coluna de data para a relação? Exemplo: **01/01/2019**.

É bom você sempre usar a data formatada e ter uma dimensão de Calendário.

Comment: Com essa função deu certo, obrigado Gabriel!